# Logstash is trying to interpret strings in JSON data. How to prevent it from doing it?

Tags: json, logstash

I have a simple logstash pipeline:

```
input { stdin {}}
filter { json { source => "message" }}
output { stdout { codec => rubydebug }}
```

And I send it simple JSON data:

```
$ echo '{"foo": "bar", "bar": 1}' | bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-10-30T14:36:19,299][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:36:19,303][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:36:19,619][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-10-30T14:36:19,641][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-10-30T14:36:19,701][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxxx",
           "bar" => 1,
    "@timestamp" => 2017-10-30T13:36:19.661Z,
       "message" => "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar\": 1}",
           "foo" => "bar"
}
[2017-10-30T14:36:22,660][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

So far so good. But problems arise when trying to parse data whose keys look like arrays:

```
$ echo '{"foo": "bar", "bar[0]": 1, "bar[1]": 2, "bar[2]": 3}' | bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-10-30T14:37:36,476][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:37:36,480][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:37:36,665][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-10-30T14:37:36,690][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-10-30T14:37:36,800][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxx",
           "bar" => {
        "0" => 1,
        "1" => 2,
        "2" => 3
    },
    "@timestamp" => 2017-10-30T13:37:36.722Z,
       "message" => "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar[0]\": 1, \"bar[1]\": 2, \"bar[2]\": 3}",
           "foo" => "bar"
}
[2017-10-30T14:37:39,700][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```

How can I prevent logstash from interpreting the strings from the JSON data and end up with:

```
{
      "@version" => "1",
          "host" => "xxxxxxx",
        "bar[0]" => 1,
        "bar[1]" => 2,
        "bar[2]" => 3,
    "@timestamp" => 2017-10-30T13:37:36.722Z,
       "message" => "{\"foo\": \"bar\", \"bar[0]\": 1, \"bar[1]\": 2, \"bar[2]\": 3}",
           "foo" => "bar"
}
```

---

Even worse, if I mix the various notations on "the same key", logstash completely crashes:

```
$ echo '{"foo": "bar", "bar": 1, "bar[1]": 2, "bar[2]": 3}' | bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/test.conf "--path.settings" "/etc/logstash"
Sending Logstash's logs to /usr/share/logstash/logs which is now configured via log4j2.properties
[2017-10-30T14:38:02,850][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"fb_apache", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/fb_apache/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:38:02,854][INFO ][logstash.modules.scaffold] Initializing module {:module_name=>"netflow", :directory=>"/usr/share/logstash/modules/netflow/configuration"}
[2017-10-30T14:38:03,103][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Starting pipeline {"id"=>"main", "pipeline.workers"=>4, "pipeline.batch.size"=>125, "pipeline.batch.delay"=>5, "pipeline.max_inflight"=>500}
[2017-10-30T14:38:03,127][INFO ][logstash.pipeline        ] Pipeline main started
[2017-10-30T14:38:03,207][INFO ][logstash.agent           ] Successfully started Logstash API endpoint {:port=>9600}
[2017-10-30T14:38:03,222][ERROR][logstash.pipeline        ] Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. {"exception"=>"org.logstash.bivalues.LongBiValue cannot be cast to org.logstash.ConvertedList", "backtrace"=>["org.logstash.Accessors.setChild(Accessors.java:109)", "org.logstash.Accessors.set(Accessors.java:18)", "org.logstash.Event.setField(Event.java:161)", "org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent.ruby_set_field(JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:132)", "org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$2$0$ruby_set_field.call(JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$2$0$ruby_set_field.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)", "org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)", "org.jruby.RubyHash$13.visit(RubyHash.java:1355)", "org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:648)", "org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:634)", "org.jruby.RubyHash.iteratorVisitAll(RubyHash.java:1306)", "org.jruby.RubyHash.each_pairCommon(RubyHash.java:1351)", "org.jruby.RubyHash.each19(RubyHash.java:1342)", "org.jruby.RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.call(RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)", "org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:183)", "org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockPassNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockPassNode.java:32)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)", "org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606)", "org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613)", "org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)", "org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)", "org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)", "org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)", "org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)", "org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.interpret(DAsgnNode.java:110)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:300)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.ProcMethod.call(ProcMethod.java:64)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)", "org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)", "org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)", "org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)", "org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.ast.WhileNode.interpret(WhileNode.java:131)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:219)", "org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)", "org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38)", "org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)", "org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)", "org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)", "org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)", "org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:300)", "org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:230)", "org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:103)", "java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)"]}
Exception in thread "[main]>worker1" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.logstash.bivalues.LongBiValue cannot be cast to org.logstash.ConvertedList
    at org.logstash.Accessors.setChild(Accessors.java:109)
    at org.logstash.Accessors.set(Accessors.java:18)
    at org.logstash.Event.setField(Event.java:161)
    at org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent.ruby_set_field(JrubyEventExtLibrary.java:132)
    at org.logstash.ext.JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$2$0$ruby_set_field.call(JrubyEventExtLibrary$RubyEvent$INVOKER$i$2$0$ruby_set_field.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallTwoArgNode.interpret(CallTwoArgNode.java:59)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash$13.visit(RubyHash.java:1355)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.visitLimited(RubyHash.java:648)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.visitAll(RubyHash.java:634)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.iteratorVisitAll(RubyHash.java:1306)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.each_pairCommon(RubyHash.java:1351)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash.each19(RubyHash.java:1342)
    at org.jruby.RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.call(RubyHash$INVOKER$i$0$0$each19.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:316)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:145)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:183)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockPassNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockPassNode.java:32)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:204)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:211)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.cacheAndCall(CachingCallSite.java:336)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:179)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:188)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgBlockNode.interpret(FCallOneArgBlockNode.java:34)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.IfNode.interpret(IfNode.java:118)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:157)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.yield(Block.java:142)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.eachCommon(RubyArray.java:1606)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray.each(RubyArray.java:1613)
    at org.jruby.RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.call(RubyArray$INVOKER$i$0$0$each.gen)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callBlock(CachingCallSite.java:143)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.callIter(CachingCallSite.java:154)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:64)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.LocalAsgnNode.interpret(LocalAsgnNode.java:123)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallOneArgNode.interpret(CallOneArgNode.java:57)
    at org.jruby.ast.DAsgnNode.interpret(DAsgnNode.java:110)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:300)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.ProcMethod.call(ProcMethod.java:64)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:210)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DynamicMethod.call(DynamicMethod.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.CallNoArgBlockNode.interpret(CallNoArgBlockNode.java:60)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.executeBody(RescueNode.java:221)
    at org.jruby.ast.RescueNode.interpret(RescueNode.java:116)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:182)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:203)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:168)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallOneArgNode.interpret(FCallOneArgNode.java:36)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.ast.WhileNode.interpret(WhileNode.java:131)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_METHOD(ASTInterpreter.java:74)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.InterpretedMethod.call(InterpretedMethod.java:225)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.methods.DefaultMethod.call(DefaultMethod.java:219)
    at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:202)
    at org.jruby.ast.FCallTwoArgNode.interpret(FCallTwoArgNode.java:38)
    at org.jruby.ast.NewlineNode.interpret(NewlineNode.java:105)
    at org.jruby.ast.BlockNode.interpret(BlockNode.java:71)
    at org.jruby.evaluator.ASTInterpreter.INTERPRET_BLOCK(ASTInterpreter.java:112)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.evalBlockBody(Interpreted19Block.java:206)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.yield(Interpreted19Block.java:194)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Interpreted19Block.call(Interpreted19Block.java:125)
    at org.jruby.runtime.Block.call(Block.java:101)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:300)
    at org.jruby.RubyProc.call(RubyProc.java:230)
    at org.jruby.internal.runtime.RubyRunnable.run(RubyRunnable.java:103)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
[2017-10-30T14:38:06,153][WARN ][logstash.agent           ] stopping pipeline {:id=>"main"}
```